# Defining a function in Python (There's a big catch)

Tags: python

So a few days ago we got this exercise where we need to make a function that takes two lists as input and calculates the difference of their averages.

Sounds simple enough, but there are a few catches:

- the entire thing needs to be one line long
- you can absolutely NOT use ':'

They encouraged us to use 'import', 'help()' and 'dir()'.

The thing is that I know how to make it only one line long, but the no ':' is really annoying.

The way I see it, I first need to define a function (without code) then change it's 'func_code' attr.

Any ideas on how can I do it?
And how do the params fit into this?
Any answer is appreciated!!!

Edit: thanks for all the answers and the creative minds that said char(58) is the solution, it is really creative and I haven't thought of that solution but it's not allowed since you are using ':' even though not directly.

Comment: To be clear, no `:` or no `;` ?

Comment: **I know how to make it only one line** - prove it

Comment: Tried `numpy` which has a `mean(list)` method?

Answer (score 1):

No `:` means you can't use lambda. That leaves higher-order functions or `eval` trickery.

```
eval('lambda a,b{}sum(a)/len(a)-sum(b)/len(b)'.format(chr(58)))
```

This meets the letter of the law, but violates its spirit.

Unfortunately, without a function composition function, higher-order functions don't work very well. Implementing one without `:` is tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what should be a fairly self-contained solution, using a pickled code object. I've created it in Python 3.6, and the specific bytestring is very likely to be version specific, but you can create your own version pretty easily using the expanded code below. Anyway, here's the oneliner:

```
f = __import__('types').FunctionType(__import__('pickle').loads(b'\x80\x03cipykernel.codeutil\ncode_ctor\nq\x00(K\x02K\x00K\x02K\x04KCC t\x00|\x00\x83\x01t\x01|\x00\x83\x01\x1b\x00t\x00|\x01\x83\x01t\x01|\x01\x83\x01\x1b\x00\x18\x00S\x00q\x01N\x85q\x02X\x03\x00\x00\x00sumq\x03X\x03\x00\x00\x00lenq\x04\x86q\x05X\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x06X\x01\x00\x00\x00bq\x07\x86q\x08X\x1e\x00\x00\x00<ipython-input-1-384cc87bd499>q\tX\x16\x00\x00\x00difference_of_averagesq\nK\x01C\x02\x00\x01q\x0b))tq\x0cRq\r.'), globals())
```

Here's what I'm doing without the one-line shenanigans:

```
import types   # replace these import statements with calls to __import__ in the oneliner
import pickle

def difference_of_averages(a, b):
    return sum(a)/len(a) - sum(b)/len(b)

payload = pickle.dumps(difference_of_averages.__code__) # embed as a literal in the oneliner

f = types.FunctionType(pickle.loads(payload), globals())
```

Hmm, having tried this on the few different interpreters I have at hand, it looks like my pickle string includes some nonsense from the IPython interpreter I created it in. If you get errors using my string, I'd suggest just building your own (which, if it contains any junk, will at least be junk compatible with your environment).

Comment: That's what I was trying to do :) Nice to see it complete!

Answer (score 0):

Not using ':' is tricky because you normally use it to define the function body, like this:

```
def average(number_list):
    return sum(number_list) / len(number_list)
```

However, I know of one way to define a function that doesn't require require writing a block for its body:  You can assign a lambda function (or even an already-defined function) to a function you want to define, simply by using the equal sign (`=`).  For example, if you want to create an `average()` function, you might write:

```
average = lambda number_list: sum(number_list) / len(number_list)
```

`average` might look like a variable, but you can use it as a function.  It simply calls the lambda function that takes a number_list as input and returns the average value of the number_list.  You can call it like this:

```
value = average([10, 11, 12])  # sets value to 11
```

Now, lambda functions can only have one line.  But that's not really a problem for you, since your task requires you to only use one line.

Do you understand what to do now?  Your exercise requires you to find the average of two lists, so you might consider using a lambda function that takes two inputs (instead of just one, like in the example I gave above).  Also bear in mind that you need to return the difference, and if the difference should always be positive, consider using Python's `abs()` function somewhere in your code.

**Edit:**  Well, gilch's response made me realize that I can't use `lambda` because even they use `:`.  So apparently you can't use my advice.  It's still good to know about lambda functions, though.

The fact that you are encouraged to use `import` makes me wonder if it's okay for you to use an already-defined function from some module to define your own function.  Kind of like this:

```
import math; average = math.difference_of_averages
```

However, that depends on you being able to find a (probably standard) function that does exactly what you want.  (I've briefly checked the `math` and `numpy` modules, and haven't found anything that matches yet.)

And maybe this means that you can create a module and define it anyway you like.  The module is in its own world, so it's not constrained to the rules of your exercise.

Then again, maybe not.

So unless you want to "sneak-in" a `:` in an `eval` statement (as gilch suggested), like this:

```
average = eval('lambda number_list' + chr(58) + ' sum(number_list) / len(number_list)')
```

there's no way I know of off hand to avoidi using `:`.